# Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) strings.xml (Android SDK / Eclipse)

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, string

I have a very simple strings.xml file however I still seem to be getting an error on it (and I have no idea why!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Linking Manager</string>
<string name="button1">Linking Manager</string>
</resources>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: there is no error in this...post error log here

Comment: clear project, or restart eclipse.

Comment: I tried the above code in my system .Its working here.

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse just open string.xml and then press `ctrl`+`shift`+`F`
This will format your source code.

Comment: Nevermind! I figured it out... (duplicate names for each string was causing a conflict - changed the names - issue resolved)


- Amani Swann

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no spaces before and after

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Also clean project.

If all else fails, delete the XML file and recreate it and paste it back again. It doesn't give any errors when I use it.

Comment: No spaces - cleaned project - same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error happen because I had a tiny little backtick at the front of the line where the error was. Didn't notice typing it and it was hard to see so far away from the indented lines.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue because R.java took a crap on me. After I fixed it, I was unable to run the program because of this error. I went into the bottom tab that says "Problems", just before the tab @Javadoc, Declaration, Console, LogCat, and Properties. I saw some errors there and I deleted them. Since the code was fine it was able to run back up.

I had this issue a long time ago, and because I didn't know how to solve it I just created an entire new project. Hopefully this will help someone else down the line.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have accidently copied `Drawable` files into `res/values`, not `res/drawable`.

For sure, `Drawable` files are never well-formed XML files... How silly. :s